# Create webservice using Nusoap that requires authentication on PHP

Tags: php, web-services, codeigniter, nusoap

I have web service server using Nusoap on codeigniter, I wonder how I could add an authentication to it?

thanks

Comment: What type of authentication? What have you tried?

Comment: actually a list of options is the correct answer I am looking for , thanks

Comment: Have you read the NuSOAP help documentation regarding supported authentication options?  Here is the link for a forum search http://sourceforge.net/search/?group_id=57663&type_of_search=forums&group_forum_id=193579&words=authentication&search=Search